# Two different values for color of the same bar

Tags: python, seaborn

The following code is to getting the color for every class in the dataset:

```
data = data.sort_values(by="Sentiment")
sentiment=data['Sentiment'].unique()
palette = sns.husl_palette(len(sentiment), l=0.7)
SAge_Graph = sns.countplot(x='Age', hue='Sentiment', 
data=data,palette=palette ,order=sorted(unique_age_groups))
legendInf = {}

for sentiment, color in zip(sentiment, palette):
legendInf[matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(color)] = sentiment
print(legendInf)
```

Which gave me the following output :

```
{'#f8889a': 'Negative', '#57bf36': 'Neutral', '#59b0f6': 'Positive'}
```

In the following code I iterate over every bar to get its coordinate and color :

```
bars = [rect for rect in SAge_Graph.get_children() if isinstance(rect, matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)]

barInfo={}
barInfo['coordinates']=[]
barInfo['colors']=[]
for bar in bars :
w,h=bar.get_width(),bar.get_height()
x0,y0=bar.xy
x1, y1 = x0 + w, y0
x2, y2 = x0, y0 + h
x3, y3 = x0 + w, y0 + h

barInfo['coordinates'].append(((x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)))

barInfo['colors'].append(matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(bar.get_facecolor()))
```

Which give me the following output :

```
    coordinates   colors
0  ((-0.4, 0), (-0.13333333333333336, 0), (-0.4, ...  #ea96a3

1  ((2.8666666666666667, 0), (3.1333333333333333,...  #60ae47

2  ((3.1333333333333333, 0), (3.4, 0), (3.1333333...  #6daee2
```

And the color is not the  same in both output any idea about why this differences?

Comment: Check the `saturation` argument of `barplot`. And please stop posting code that isn't minimal or runnable.

Comment: great thanks It works,next Time I will ensure that the code is minimal or  at lest runnable